# Developing in an academic institute

Tags: software-development, project-management, teamwork, academia

We are currently an academic institute of around 50 people. The institute does typical industry research, batteries, metals, magnets, etc. Recently, they began more and more relying on algorithmic developments for their evaluation. Most of the recent research results depend in one way or another on custom-built solutions.

We are currently building these small solutions internally on a per-need basis. I joined the team 1 year ago as a "Machine Learning Expert" but my origin is in computer science and programming. I have some experience in DevOps, Software Project Management, and CI/TDD, so I have concepts of how things *could* be organized. I will be working on my Ph.D. there, so going to another place is not really an option. 4 or 5 more people have at least some experience coding, depending on what you count as experience.

We have data management by chaos and network drives, there is no CI or TDD, no common code-base, everything is pushed on network drives via mercurial (if at all, often it stays local) we slowly have to start using docker because some of the hardware requires it, but we don't have the time to get to the point where it starts saving time, we have high fluctuation and that's only some of the problems you can imagine. Also, we have tons of meetings on how to structure stuff and improve the situation (theoretically). Welcome to academia.

The management structure is "by objective" and the DevOps horizon ends at excel. How you do DevOps in excel? You don't. So nobody really cares what we do, how we do, or even who does what as long as you document your stuff in PowerPoint and application guys can use it. There are multiple people supervising multiple students, which sometimes have some sort of coding experience and add to code-abyss. As long as stuff gets published no one cares. In my opinion, working like this and continuing in such a way with the ever-increasing growth and demand for custom-built solutions and software, is tremendously short-sighted, to put it gently. I mean, imagine how efficient a working development team would be compared to *that*. I could go on vacation for half a year and still be more productive.

But what do I know, I've been working there for a year now and my "real" software development career is limited to half a year (which only taught me what I am missing out on, not how to go about it from scratch).

So I need someone with more experience to tell me

- what options I have,
- who to involve and how to implement it (remember there are no hierarchies, everybody manages everyone),
- how *not* to be the complete douche that starts here working, wanting to change everything.

I think I am somehow just scared that I don't have the time and resources to change anything at all. But anyway I thought I'd give it a shot here as there are people with much more experience than I have, either Management or Developer. From my phrasing, it's probably clear how desperate I am for anything that does not include yet another work-level meeting where we discuss how we could theoretically improve stuff.

Answer (score 4):

Change is disruptive, and people kinda hate it. No amount of convincing someone is going to change their mind as much as showing them.

I'd pick something where I'd get maximum impact, where impact is the wow-factor. How many people's lives can you make easier, and by how much etc.

Don't bother implementing whole paradigms. Take the bits that are going to impress and improve things in the short term. Don't bother about checking all the boxes. Do what makes sense.

Don't listen to people that go, "that isn't proper DevOps", or "that isn't proper Scrum". Do what makes sense and that is going to get maximum buy in.

Once you gain a foothold, you can start to look at expanding and refining your processes.

But the short term is all about finding that bit that will free up some bandwidth, and bring people onside.

Comment: Thanks for your reassuring words!

Answer (score 0):

Somebody with a permanent academic position here; who never held a "real job". (Btw, this question would likely fit on [academia.se](https://academia.stackexchange.com/) as well, and would get you answers by more people like with primary experience in academia).

Your question title states that you want to *develop* in an academic environment. Yet, a few paragraphs in, you say *you will be working on your PhD there*. Therefore, a very important question: **are you hired in a role as a (software) developer, or as a PhD student** (in computer science)**?**

While a PhD candidature/studentship (in CD) is a fully salaried job in some countries and just supported by a bursary in others, in practice it is a job. It is a job with some overlapping skills and requirements with software development, but **it is fundamentally a different job**.

**Researchers are (usually) not expected to write production code**. Researchers should also not get completely lazy and write bad code, but researchers test research ideas. A researcher in chemistry might, for example, try and figure out how to synthesise a new chemical -- but will NOT be expected to construct a mass-production plant (even if they "write the theoretical instructions" for how to do it). That is the job of (industry) engineers. Similarly, a computer science researcher would write the code to implement his new concepts, and to test them. **The goal is, as you correctly notice, to publish in in peer-reviewed research venues** and therefore share this work with the academic community. Repeatability of experiments is quite important, but integration and transforming research code into production code should be a job of engineers, in my opinion. I did not take up a research position to do a software development or engineering job.

An issue you identify, that the team's code base is floating in the air and is not well maintained, is indeed an issue of many research institutes. Having and integrated an maintained code base does, of course, increase everybody's productivity -- the teams that I've seen handle it best **hired engineers** (not researchers) especially for this purpose.

You seem to be asking why a (perhaps badly organised) academic department is not organised like a software development department. You seem to be asking **how to *focus* on software development in your role as a PhD candidate**, and I really think the answer is **you do not**.

<sub><sup>Oh, and the only reason I have even seen the words DevOps and Scrum is because I read this particular SE; they were never used in any context of any of my research positions.</sup></sub>

Comment: I'm upvoting penelope's answer because it is relevant and useful. Academia is a turbulent and varied mixture. A grad student might be doing something on a summer project; another might be involved with the project for five years.  Post docs might be bringing in relevant large scale coding experience, or just enough to complete a dissertation.  It's important to clarify what the OP is expected to do, because that will constrain them.

Comment: Well, as often in life, it's not that simple. I am a self-funded Ph.D. candidate in a major foreign university (I have to pay tuition and don't get any money at all for this position), have a government-funded part-time job at this institute (university of applied sciences), additionally I am working as a technology transfer specialist in the industry to make the rest of the money required for a living. If I am stepping down on either of the last two, I am losing my Ph.D. For me, industry and academia are inseparable. I'd love to follow your advice, but it's unaffordable resource-wise.

Answer (score 0):

I work in an academic environment (hired last fall), and am currently helping a team go from where you are to a better place.  Google 'reproducible research' for a start, and see who is doing this at your university.  Find out if you have a data librarian, and talk with them.

This is actually a big drive in academia (varying by field, of course).  More and more funders (and the government) are requiring such practices.

Comment: Could I clarify, were you hired as a technician/developer/engineer or as a researcher (PhD student/postdoc/lecturer/prof)? As mentioned in my answer, hiring an engineer (or a smaller team of) to keep maintain the code-base of a team is brilliant, and I have seen it work very well. On the other hand, asking a researcher to plan such structure is out of scope of their position.

Comment: Penelope, I'm a data manager/data analyst (statistician with a MS and some Ph.D. coursework).  I'm working in a statistical group in a university; one of the group's goals is to roll out what is called 'reproducible research' at this university (in conjunction with other groups on campus).   In one project I'll be working with a professor and Ph.D. students to train and work with them on their research.  The Ph.D. students will *start* their research work using these methods.  Since these methods involve reproducibility, the next group should inherit and extend.

Comment: I appreciate that change is happening at least in some places. People like me will thank you a lot when they have to transfer technology to industry, are expected to carry out research, and still have to develop / engineer for other use cases at these institutes.